# why is data not being passed from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following form

```
<form id="dataForm" method="post">
  <h2 id="formheader"> Update Description</h2>
    <div>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="orginalName" type="text" name="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Description:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newDescription" type="text" name="description">
    </div>
    <div id="theSubmit">
      <button id="editDesButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

and the following javascript function

```
function editDescription(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("orginalName");
    var Description = document.getElementById("newDescription");

    var data_seen = false;
        // this is a flag to record whether any data has been seen. Used in the guard ofthe alert statement.
    if (name.value !="" && Description.value !=""){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editDescription.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Description=" + Description.value);
    }
    if (!data_seen) {
        alert("please enter some data");
    }
   }

submitButton = document.getElementById("editDesButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", editDescription);
```

and this small bit of php

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
     $Description = $_POST['description'];

     if($Name !="" && $Description !=""){
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Description = '$Description' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
```

If i run the form and use `action="editDescription.php` then the sql is run and the table is updated to how i want it but then when i run the javascript on the event when the button is clicked the values are not being passed in and i cannot see why, has anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Are you seeing any JS error in the console ?

Comment: "if ( ){" ? You should use the javascript console (ctrl + maj +j on Chrome)

Comment: The form is submitting, and you're using different case for the data keys and the POST variables ?

Comment: Does your `xmlhttp.open` point to the right URL? is "editDescription" in the same path as your web page?

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean sorry?

Comment: You also need to encode your url values and you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: why not you are using jQuery instead of javascript?

Comment: Unless you really want to use plain JavaScript, you better use JQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: unless you specify `type="button"` inside the button tag, the DOM treats it as Submit element, and when you click on it the form submits before getting a chance to trigger the click event. And is the extention `".PHP or .php"` in `editDescription.PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the submit feature, the browser urlencode himself (correctly) the fields. In your js code you aren't urlencoding. In most case, if you enter a space in a field or any other caracter which needs to be encoded, it'll fail. 
Second thing, in the line below, you have to use a lowercase "d" for your "description" field. PHP is case sensitive. (I recommend you to always use lowercase field names to avoid mistakes)

try:

```
 xmlhttp.send(encodeURI("Name=" + name.value + "&description=" + Description.value));
```

Maybe there is more problems. Like Pierre Emmanuel said, use the javascript console, espacially the "Network" tab to spy exactly what are you sending over the wire. You can also look what is PHP receiving with `var_dump($_POST);` for example. (or `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` if the first command fail.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code to jQuery:

```
function editDescription(){
var name = $('#orginalName').val();  //getting input field value
var description= $('#newDescription').val(); //getting input field value
$.ajax({//create an ajax request to Your.php
type: "POST",
url: "Your.php",   //your php file name
data:{"name ":name,"description":description},
success: function(data) {
    if (data) {

       alert(data);
    }
    else {
        alert('Successfully not posted.');
    }
}
});
}
submitButton = document.getElementById("editDesButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", editDescription);
```

Your.php

```
 $Name = $_POST['name'];
 $Description = $_POST['description'];

 if($Name !="" && $Description !=""){
 $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Description = '$Description' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
 $conn->exec($sql);
```